# Load content to title from tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to load (replace) text from `<h2>`

```
<h2>Text</h2>
```

to

```
<title>Here!</title>
```

How can I do it?

When I was replacing classes I used something like `$(".value").load`...
but I don't know how to do that with tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the title using the `document.title` property. So setting the title to be the content of a `h2` tag you could use:

```
document.title = $('h2').text();
```

Without jQuery

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];

if (element.textContent) {
    document.title = element.textContent;
} else {
    document.title = element.innerText; // IE < 9
}
```

Comment: @Neurofluxation — Given the code used in the question, its a reasonable assumption that jQuery is in play.

Comment: @Neurofluxation: he uses `$("value").load` in his example of what he did for replacing classes. The assumption was that if he used it previously he can still do so.

Comment: perfect, thank you. 

And how I can add some text ('h2')+"something else"?

Sorry I am beginner with JS

Comment: OK fine. I did it.

document.title = $('h2').text()+"something";